# why there is contradiction between "to give professional sittings" and "not give séances as a professional medium"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

why there is contradiction between "to give professional sittings" and "not give séances as a professional medium"?

at first the author says that Mr. Livermore helped her to give professional sittings but it is stated in the letter that she will not give séances as a professional medium. anyone can clarify about this?

> It was in this year 1871 that Kate Fox's visit to England was brought
>   about through the generosity of Mr. Charles F. Livermore, a prominent
>   banker of New York, in gratitude for the consolation he had received
>   from her wonderful powers, and to advance the cause of Spiritualism.
>   He provided for all her needs, and thus removed any necessity for her
>   **to give professional sittings**. He also arranged for her to be
>   accompanied by a congenial woman companion. In a letter [The Spiritual
>   Magazine, 1871, pp. 525-6.] to Mr. Benjamin Coleman, a well-known
>   worker in the Spiritualist movement, Mr. Livermore says: Miss Fox,
>   taken all in all, is no doubt the most wonderful living medium. Her
>   character is irreproachable and pure. I have received so much through
>   her powers of mediumship during the past ten years which is solacing,
>   instructive and astounding, that I feel greatly indebted to her, and
>   desire to have her taken good care of while absent from her home and
>   friends. His further remarks have some bearing possibly on the later
>   sad events of her life: That you may the more thoroughly understand
>   her idiosyncrasies, permit me to explain that she is a sensitive of
>   the highest order and of childlike simplicity; she feels keenly the
>   atmospheres of everyone with whom she is brought in contact, and to
>   that degree that at times she becomes exceedingly nervous and
>   apparently capricious. For this reason I have advised her not to sit
>   in dark séances, that she may avoid the irritation arising from the
>   suspicion of sceptics, mere curiositymongers, and lovers of the
>   marvellous. The perfection of the manifestations to be obtained
>   through her depends upon her surroundings, and in proportion as she is
>   in rapport or sympathy with you does she seem receptive of spiritual
>   power. The communications through her are very remarkable, and have
>   come to me frequently from my wife (Estelle), in perfect idiomatic
>   French, and sometimes in Spanish and Italian, whilst she herself is
>   not acquainted with any of these languages. You will understand all
>   this, but these explanations may be necessary for others. As I have
>   said, **she will not give séances as a professional medium**, but I hope
>   she will do all the good she can in furtherance of the great truth, in
>   a quiet way, while she remains in England.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: Look at the entire sentence: "He provided for all her needs, and thus removed any necessity for her to give professional sittings." Does this say she was giving professional sittings, or not giving professional sitting?  Or is that not clear?  If not, we can answer that question.

Comment: @please explain and give me an answer.

Comment: @my giving professional sitting against not giving séances as a professional medium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statements are not contradictory.

The first statement says, "He provided for all her needs, and thus removed any necessity for her to give professional sittings."

Broken apart, the sentence looks like:

*He provided for all her needs* - he provided housing and food for her (or maybe he provided her with money so that she could pay for housing and food)

*and thus removed any necessity* - and for this reason (because he was paying for her housing and food), it was not necessary

*for her to give professional sittings* - for her to charge money in exchange for doing her psychic work

All together: *because he was providing her with housing and food, it was not necessary for her to work as a professional psychic.*

*It was not necessary for her to work as a professional psychic* has the same basic meaning as *she will not give séances as a professional medium*.